# R ifelse statement only return number

Tags: r, if-statement

This is `house$room`
[image]

```
type<-c('2室1厅','2室2厅','3室2厅','1室1厅','4室2厅',
        '3室1厅','1室','2室','1室2厅','5室2厅','4室3厅')
```

[image]

Why does `ifelse` return only numbers?

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that `house$room` is `factor` and it gets coerced to `integer` storage values within the `ifelse` loop.  One option is to convert to `character` class

```
ifelse(house$room %in% type, as.character(house$room), '不要张贴图片')
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the issue here, and @akrun's code fixes the problem. Try it yourself if you're not convinced: `x <- factor(letters); ifelse(x %in% sample(letters, 13), x, "something else"); ifelse(x %in% sample(letters, 13), as.character(x), "something else")`

Comment: @akrun thank you for your help - you are a true saviour and you make my life better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ifelse(house$room == type, '不要张贴图片', as.character(house$room))
```